# Ruby Classes within Classes (or Modules within Modules)

Tags: ruby

As I'm reading different Ruby books, I've noticed that Ruby classes can be defined within other Ruby classes or modules.  Here's an example of a class within a class:

```
class Outerclass
  def foobar
    puts "FOOBAR"
  end

  class Innerclass   
    def barfoo
      puts "BARFOO"
    end
  end
end
```

Here's some code that I ran in IRB to try to understand this conceptually:

```
oc = Outerclass.new # => #<Outerclass:0x00000100a46478>

Outerclass.instance_methods(false) # => [:foobar]

ic = Outerclass::Innerclass.new # => #<Outerclass::Innerclass:0x00000100a0b120>

ic = Outerclass::Innerclass.instance_methods(false) # => [:barfoo]
```

Here are my questions:

1. When the ruby interpreter first encounters my Class definition code above, does it go through the methods I've written and store it somewhere?  I know that the instance method "foobar" doesn't actually get run since there's no call being made to it within the Outerclass definition.
2. Piggybacking off the 1st question, what about when Ruby encounters the class Innerclass?  What happens here?
3. In general, what are some reasons why you would want to have classes within classes?  Are there any advantages to doing this?
4. Does an instance of Outerclass know anything about the class Innerclass?
5. Does an instance of Innerclass know anything about the class Outerclass?

Appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When the interpreter is going through this file, it is assigning classes like this:

```
OuterClass = Class.new do 
  def foobar
    puts "FOOBAR"
  end

  InnerClass = Class.new do   
    def barfoo
      puts "BARFOO"
    end
  end
end
```

So when Ruby encounters the nested class, it assigns it to constant `InnerClass` which is assigned to constant `OuterClass`  They have no relation to each other whatsoever.

The `InnerClass` has no inheritance to `OuterClass`:

```
  InnerClass.ancestors
  => [InnerClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

When you call `OuterClass::InnerClass` constant you are refering to the `InnerClass` constant that is namespaced under the `OuterClass` contstant which equals the Class.new statement assigned to it.

A good book to read about this is "Metaprogramming Ruby".  It goes into the details of classes, singletons, modules etc.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the insight.  As a follow up, are you basically saying that even though, structurally, it looks like Innerclass is within Outerclass, when Ruby sees these 2 classes, it just creates 2 constants?  How would it be different if I moved the Innerclass definition out of the Outerclass definition?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes these are now 2 constants referring to 2 classes.  However the InnerClass constant is namespaced to the outerclass.  If you moved innerclass out it would be the same besides the fact that OuterClass::Innerclass would now be a top level constant and OuterClass will not have a reference to it.

Comment: To put it more simply: there is no inner and outer class. There are just two completely and utterly unrelated classes. One just happens to be assigned to a constant namespaced inside the other. Ruby doesn't support nested classes, unfortunately. To understand how nested classes work and how they are fundamentally different from what you are seeing here, take a look at the Beta programming language, which introduced nested classes and the Newspeak programming language (and especially its libraries) which uses them to great effect.

Comment: Yes Jörg that is essentially what I was trying to say.  You put it more clearly. +1

Comment: Ah ok, so even though one class is defined within another, instances of either class won't actually know anything about the other class right?

Comment: Yes there is nothing happening other than a constant inside the outer class pointing to the separate inner class. They have no inheritance or shared methods.  They are 100% separate classes.

Comment: @MichaelPapile how would you monkey patch a subclass like this, it seems like doing so would override the previous constant