# Ruby top level Contstant loading issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model in my Rails app:

```
class Comment
  class Digest
  end
end
```

When I attempt to load it in the console, I get:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.2)
irb(main):001:0> Comment::Digest
(irb):1: warning: toplevel constant Digest referenced by Comment::Digest
=> Digest
irb(main):002:0> require "comment/digest"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Comment::Digest
=> Comment::Digest
```

If I change the name of `Digest` to `Other`, it works fine. The class is for digest notifications and I'd like to keep the name if I can get around it relatively easily.

```
class Comment
  class Other
  end
end

irb(main):003:0> Comment::Other
=> Comment::Other
```

If I add an initializer to load the model, it works ok:

```
# config/initializers/comment_digest_loader.rb

require "comment"
require "comment/digest"
```

I realize it's not being loaded using `const_get` b/c the Digest module already exists. Just not sure the best way to handle this.

Comment: may be worth reading the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739640/ruby-classes-within-classes-or-modules-within-modules

Comment: Maybe I'm an idiot, but that link makes total sense and I've even read the book referenced. Still a little lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you receive occurs when you try to reference a constant within a constant which exists in top level but *does not* exist in the referencing constant:

```
Comment::String
# warning: toplevel constant String referenced by Comment::String
```

Make sure that the class `Comment::Digest` is declared *before* you try to reference it.

---

Update:

It seems that Rail's autoload feature depends on `const_missing` being called, since the constant `Digest` already exists in toplevel, `const_misssing` is apparently not called, and the error is thrown instead of the class being loaded.

To verify this, try running the code without requiring the `digest` constant.

To mitigate this, you can try eager-loading the models:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```

Comment: see my edit, agreed! Because it's in Rails, I would've thought the file `app/models/comment/digest.rb` would be loaded. Am I missing something?

Comment: Running that does fix it. I've also edited the post about using an initializer. Is that too hacky?

Comment: @user2261909 - some would say this is the proper way to go: http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Answer (score 0):

You should have the proper folder structure in order for ruby to automatically load your class. In your case, your `Comment::Digest` class should be defined inside the folder `comment`.

If you don't have the proper folder structure, you will have to explicitly require your class before using it.

```
require "comment/digest"

Comment::Digest
```

Its giving you the warning because, ruby didn't automatically load the class `Comment::Digest`. But it knows about the top level ruby module `Digest`

Comment: The file is in `app/models/comment/digest.rb`. I added the require line and still get the same thing :/