# Ruby MyClass = Class.new autoloading best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have class defined like this, and I been told this could cause problems with Rails autoload. What is the reason behind this? and when should we use Class.new?

```
class Integration < ActiveRecord::Base
  MYobIdentifier = Class.new(Integration)
end
```

Comment: I think if you go through these two links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739640/ruby-classes-within-classes-or-modules-within-modules, http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/ you will get your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a constant (in this case your class name) cannot be find then Ruby will attempt to find it using a filename based on the constant name. In this case it will search for `MYobIdentifier` in a file called `m_yob_identifier` (There are a few different places it would look for this file)

As long as you can be sure that the `Integration` class is loaded before any attempt is made to ys `MYobIdentifier` then it will always be defined and you do not need to worry.

Also in your case, I assume you will access it as `Integration::MYobIdentifier` in which case `Integration` will always be loaded before trying to resolve the constant.

Note: I think you would be better off capitalizing the class as `MyObIdentifier`

Answer (score 1):

As the stackoverflow question linked in a comment covers,

```
class A
  class B
  end
end
```

becomes this under the hood:

```
A = Class.new do
  B = Class.new
end
```

One additional detail of your example is that another class `Integration` is being passed as an argument to `Class.new`. This sets up inheritance. You can check whether one class inherits from another using `ClassA < ClassB`; this returns `true` or `nil`:

```
class A
  class B
  end
end
A::B < A
# => nil

class A
  B = Class.new(A)
end
A::B < A
# => true
```

this second example is the same as this:

```
class A
  class B < A
  end
end
A::B < A
# => true
```